# What are the boundary conditions for an ideal fluid in a frictionless pool?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, boundary-conditions, differential-equations, classical-field-theory

Suppose you want to numerically solve the classical 2D waves equation for an ideal incompressible fluid in a square pool.  The pool's walls are frictionless, so the fluid could vertically move freely along the walls and fall back (without turbulences).  I consider only the motion on the 2D surface of the fluid.  We know the *initial state* (or **initial conditions**) of the surface: $z(0, x, y) = \mathfrak{F}(x, y)$ and $\dot{z}(0, x, y) = \mathfrak{G}(x, y)$, where $\mathfrak{F}$ and $\mathfrak{G}$ are arbitrary smooth functions.

What should be the **boundary conditions** in that case?

This is not like a typical membrane fixed on a square hanger (i.e. $z(t, 0, y) = z(t, L, y) = z(t, x, 0) = z(t, x, L) = 0$).  So I would like to know the equations in cartesian coordinates that need to be imposed on the wave function $z(t, x, y)$ (except the second order waves equation, of course).

Comment: If the fluid can move vertically I think you need the 3D wave equation.

Comment: @user45664, certainly not!  The vertical motion of the surface is the wave disturbance (i.e. wave function $z(t, x, y)$) propagating on the surface.  The transverse waves are propagating ON the surface, not in the bulk under the surface (or that would be another problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fluid at a frictionless wall you would call this a free slip boundary condition. Typically they're not imposed at walls but at a free surface.

No friction means that there is no gradient in the wall-normal direction of the wall-parallel component.

$$ \frac{v_\parallel}{dn}=0$$

Hence there is no viscous friction. Obviously, the wall is impermeable, so you also have

$$ v_\perp=0.$$

We can convert this to your problem, where you solve for $z(x, y, t)$. The impermeability constraint is automatically satisfied by the choice for $z$ and $v_\parallel=\frac{dz}{dt}$. Hence, the free slip condition leads to

$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial t \partial x} = 0 $$

at $x$ boundaries.

Comment: Please, can you give the full equations (with cartesian components and partial derivatives) that would be imposed, at boundaries, for the wave function $z(t, x, y)$?

Comment: @Cham I do not have enough information. Is $z$ the elevation of the surface? What are the boundaries? What $dn$ is depends on the boundary of your domain. $v_\perp=0$ is 0 by definition in your problem, I think. $v_\parallel=\frac{dz}{dt}$ if I understand it correctly.

Comment: The boundaries are located at $x = -L$, $x = +L$, $y = -L$ and $y = +L$.  The coordinate $z(t, x, y)$ locates the surface of the fluid, so yes it's the elevation of the surface.  It should be free at the boundary, with any vertical velocity.

Comment: So what is the part that you are missing? You would get $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial t \partial x}=0$ at the $y=\pm L$.

Comment: A second order constraint?  I never saw that before.  Maybe you should include this into your answer.

Comment: @Cham Well, this is because your primary variable is the position, rather than the velocity. I guess you already have another second order condition for the curvature at the boundary (i.e., surface tension). I will update the answer.

Comment: I will have to test this into my Mathematica numerical code...

Comment: Good luck! You'll probably get some stability issues at your first few tries, but I hope you can get it to work.

Comment: Well, it works only if I set $$\frac{\partial^2 \, z}{\partial t \, \partial x}\Big|_{x \, = \, 0 \, \text{and} \, L} = 0,$$ and $$\frac{\partial^2 \, z}{\partial t \, \partial y}\Big|_{y \, = \, 0 \, \text{and} \, L} = 0,$$ but not if I use $$\frac{\partial^2 \, z}{\partial t \, \partial x}\Big|_{y \, = \, 0 \, \text{and} \, L} = 0$$ and $$\frac{\partial^2 \, z}{\partial t \, \partial y}\Big|_{x \, = \, 0 \, \text{and} \, L} = 0.$$ But then I get some weird (and still credible) reflexions at the boundaries.  I don't know if a fluid really does that.

Comment: The one you used makes sense, because that would be the wall normal component (my bad). You would expect reflection at boundaries of the wave equation, right?

Comment: Well, I was expecting a boundary without boundary effect, so the waves could pass through the walls without reflections.  I was wrong.  I guess I can't get rid of the reflections, unless I push the boundaries far away from the visualization zone, in my numerical code.  I was searching for another, more efficient way, of doing this.

Comment: Well, then you should have asked a different question ;) If you don't have dissipation, putting the boundaries far away will not really help you either.

Comment: Far away boundaries are okay if the simulation time doesn't let the reflections to come in the visualization zone.  What would be your way to get rid of the reflections?

Comment: You are right about the simulation time. My thinking was to create a layer around your boundary with a different wave speed. Based on the ratio of the speeds you might get partial or no-reflection at one side of the boundary, such that wave can exit your domain, but not enter. And then you can make that side very dissipative. The question would be: what is the actual physics that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm simply trying to numerically solve waves generation that would get to infinity after a while (no reflections).  The reflections cause unnatural issues that I need to get rid.  The code is working great with far away boundaries and a "short" simulation time.  But as I said, I was looking for another way of doing this, to get a more efficient code (the Mathematica code compilation is slooow !).

Comment: You're probably better of using Green's functions for that.